# JAVA: Gazettes with Stanford NER with text list token

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

In faq stanford I found "[How do you use gazettes with Stanford NER](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#gazette)",but I would use a text file with a list of tokens, while the example is written that you have to set the class for each token, but since there are so many tokens in my file for me is a bit complicated to set the class for each tokens.